# Spring Data Rest Configuration is not reflecting as expected

Tags: spring, spring-data-rest

I have just started with Spring Data Rest (SDR) hence don't have much experience in this. I initially worked for Spring Data JPA and currently started with Spring Data Neo4j, where I have to implement SDR to generate `application/hal+json` response and exposed repository as REST service.
I am facing some weird issue, I followed the [steps](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/1.1.x/reference/htmlsingle/#d4e97) as mention in Spring Doc for SDR to configuration but somehow its not working as expected. Following is my code snippet.
**Repository**:

```
public interface MyRepository extends GraphRepository<EntityBean>,NamedIndexRepository<EntityBean>, RelationshipOperationsRepository<EntityBean>
{
    @Query(value="START .... return root;")
    List<EntityBean> findByName(@Param("name")String name);

    @Query(value="START .... return root;")
    List<EntityBean> findBySurname(@Param("surname")String surname);
}
```

**CustomMVCConfiguration**

```
@Configuration  
public class CustomMVCConfig extends RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration {

@Override
protected void configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(RepositoryRestConfiguration config)
{
    config.setResourceMappingForDomainType(EntityBean.class).addResourceMappingFor("surname").setPath("lastname").setPath("newPathABC");
    config.setResourceMappingForDomainType(EntityBean.class).addResourceMappingFor("name").setPath("firstName").setPath("newPathXYZ");
    config.setResourceMappingForRepository(MyRepository.class).addResourceMappingFor("findByName").setPath("MyPath").setRel("MyRel");
    config.setDefaultMediaType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
}}
```

When I am hitting Mapped SDR servlet url:

```
http://localhost:8080/app/sdrUrl/
```

I am getting following output:

```
{
"_links" : {
"entityBeans" : {
  "href" : "http://localhost:8080/app/sdrUrl/entityBeans{?page,size,sort}",
  "templated" : true
}
 }
}
```

and

```
"_embedded" : {
"entityBeans" : [ {
  "name" : "John",
  "surname" : "Doe",
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/app/sdrUrl/entityBeans/4194"
    }
  }
}
```

Configuration is initialized for sure, (cross checked while debugging),  Since I have explicitly set resourceMapping for domain type and repository type, what wrong happening here ?  **name** and **surname** are not replaced by **firstName** and **lastName**
**Update**  !
I am using spring-data-rest-webmvc v2.0.2.RELEASE, although I am following doc for v1.1.x, still I think it should work as expected...
**Update**

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" version="2.5"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.project.resources</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>SpringDataRest</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryRestDispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SpringDataRest</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/restdb/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Your `CustomMVCConfig` is it being assigned to respective `**WebApplicationContext` (e.g. AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ) ? I am not sure about the changes of name, but doubtful about spring configuration..

Comment: I didn't get.. actually I am not following Java Configuration as given in documentation. I am trying to setup using old web.xml style. update my question.

Comment: you are missing configuration part. have a look here : http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#beans-java-instantiating-container-web

Comment: Thanks @agpt after proper configuration of my Dispatcher Servlet, it worked..!